# Postgresql query to get last node in path

Tags: postgresql, recursion

I have a PostgreSQL table defined similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE tname(
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT,
  parent_id bigint,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES tname (id)
);
```

consider the following example

```
id | name     | parent_id
-------------------------
1  | 'root'   | NULL
2  | 'child1' | 1
3  | 'child2' | 1
4  | 'child1' | 2
5  | 'child2' | 2
```

I need my program to generate a query based on a path, for example 'root/child1/child2'
this should return row of id 5.

I made a query that kinda work, but I suspect it is less than optimal and would think it can be solved a lot better.

```
WITH root AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id
    FROM tname
    WHERE tname.parent_id IS NULL
        AND tname.name = 'root'
), b1 AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id
    FROM tname
    WHERE tname.parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM root)
        AND tname.name = 'child1'
), b2 AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id
    FROM tname
    WHERE tname.parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM b1)
        AND tname.name = 'child2'
)
SELECT *
FROM tname
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM b2)
```

I feel this is a very klumsy solution that will be very long as the path grows.

How would I solve this in a more optimal way? could RECURSIVE query be used, and would it be faster?

Comment: how many rows do you expect to be in this table?

Comment: I would like it to perform reasonably well with 500k rows, but in most cases it will be significantly lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, recursive could certainly be used and it would not necessarily be faster, but would be much easier to read and use.  Your table layout is very common, however, it'd be much easier to query if you considered putting in a "path" field that would assist in queries like this to make it faster and able to use an index.

Here's an example of a recursive query that would work easier than your example:

```
 with recursive ret(id, parent_id, path) as
    (
      select t.id,t.parent_id, '\' as path from tname t
      where t.parent_id is null
      union
      select t.id, t.parent_id, ret.path||t.name||'\' as pth from tname t
      inner join ret on ret.id=t.parent_id
    ) 
    select id, parent_id, path from ret
    where path='\my\path\'
```

Comment: This could be done even more efficiently with a plsql or sql recursive function.. if you'd be interested in that code, let me know.

Comment: Ok, I did consider using a path field, but was not sure if this was a good idea or not. I think I will look more into that as it sounds like it will be the best solution.

Comment: what do you mean by plsql or sql recursive function? sorry, im just starting to learn SQL.